# Migrate AWS Cognito users to Auth0

Tags: authentication, migration, amazon-cognito, auth0

I want to move all existing users from an AWS Cognito Pool to Auth0. Preferably with existing passwords or with on-the-fly migration if a password change is must. I see user guides online to migrate Okta/Stormpath etc users to auth0, but not seeing anything for cognito to autho ingegration. Any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to import users into Auth0:

1. [Bulk Migration](https://auth0.com/docs/users/bulk-user-imports)
2. [Automatic Migration](https://auth0.com/docs/users/configure-automatic-migration-from-your-database) (i.e. Lazy Load)

Currently, there is really no easy way to export users out of AWS Cognito. And even if you did, the exported user profile [would not include the user's hashed password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059151/can-you-export-migrate-users-out-of-aws-cognito-does-it-cause-vendor-lock-in) so it would require that the user reset their account password once migrated to Auth0 as the identity provider. Not ideal. So bulk migration is kind of out of the question.

- [AWS Cognito User Profiles Export Reference Architecture](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/cognito-user-profiles-export-reference-architecture/)
- [Export Users From Amazon Cognito User Pool](https://medium.com/@serkhazov/export-users-from-amazon-cognito-user-pool-bf57a128a9fe)

Instead, **Automatic Migration** is probably the way to go. You must [configure a Custom Database](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/custom-db/create-db-connection) in Auth0 and point it to your AWS Cognito user pool and define two scripts: one to **get** a user and another to **login** a user.

AWS doesn't expose these endpoints via an API by default, but they do have similar functions in their [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) npm package (according to **Scenario 4** in the documentation).

Thanks to [@yvovandoorn](https://gist.github.com/yvovandoorn) for writing the [javascript code](https://gist.github.com/yvovandoorn/a82906dbca19c0122edb9a1f234c245c), you can use this npm package in the Auth0 Custom Database `get-user` and `login` scripts to perform automatic migration. Just make sure you check the **Import Users to Auth0** to true under the Custom Database settings.

`get-user.js`

```js
/*
Requires Auth0 Global Variables to be set - https://auth0.com/docs/rules/configure-global-variables-for-rules
If testing locally (or not wanting to use Auth0 Global Variables):
const configuration = {
  "accessKeyId": "AKIAIBDT5G4M237CZSMQ",
  "secretAccessKey": "your-cognito-secret-access-key",
  "region": "eu-west-1",
  "UserPoolId": "eu-west-1_V69pvauTp"
*/

function getUser(username, callback) {
    const userParameters =  ["email", "email_verified", "custom:designation"];
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk@2.593.0');
    AWS.config.update({ "accessKeyId": configuration.accessKeyId, "secretAccessKey": configuration.secretAccessKey, "region": configuration.region });
    const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    cognito.adminGetUser({
        UserPoolId: configuration.UserPoolId,
        Username: username
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            if (err.code === "UserNotFoundException") return callback(null);
            else callback(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.code === "UserNotFoundException") return callback(null);
            else {
                let profile = {
                    "user_id": data.UserAttributes.find(item=>item.Name==="sub").Value,
                    "username": data.Username,
                };
                userParameters.forEach(customParameterName => {
                    profile[customParameterName] = data.UserAttributes.find(item=>item.Name===customParameterName).Value;
                });
                return callback(null, profile);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

`login.js`

```js
/*
Read StackOverflow article about potential window issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219518/aws-cognito-unauthenticated-login-error-window-is-not-defined-js

Requires Auth0 Global Variables to be set - https://auth0.com/docs/rules/configure-global-variables-for-rules

If testing locally (or not wanting to use Auth0 Global Variables):
const configuration = {
  "ClientId": "nzHNdG0XGS4qSaS5p0EZZesoIO2xfKQDRMgWPoce",
  "UserPoolId": "eu-west-1_V69pvauTp"
*/

function login(username, password, callback) {
    global.fetch = require('node-fetch@2.6.0');
    var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js@3.0.14');
    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId: configuration.UserPoolId,
        ClientId: configuration.ClientId

    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

    var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails({
        Username: username,
        Password: password
    });
    var userData = {
        Username: username,
        Pool: userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            //console.log(result);
            var idTokenPayload = result.getIdToken().payload;
            console.log(idTokenPayload);
            var profile = {
              user_id: idTokenPayload.sub,
              email: idTokenPayload.email,
              /* might want to set this to false if you're not validating email addresses */
              email_verified: true,
            };
            console.log({ result, idTokenPayload, profile });
            callback(null, profile);
        },
        onFailure: (function (err) {
            return callback(new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(username))
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: What about OAuth 2 users? (federation identities)